# script to edit config files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm working on a script that would allow me to add, remove, or edit config files.  I have tested it a little and it seems like I got it to work at least with a single file, but I would like to be able to just do *.config or fi*.config and have it perform the desired action.

I would appreciate any help.

Config file looks looks similar to this just bigger

```
-- Config File
-- Environment DEV7
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- General properties
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

com.x.yy.zz.version=2.0.2

com.x.yy.zz.instanceRole.ServerA=PRIMARY
com.x.yy.zz.instanceRole.ServerB=SECONDARY

com.x.yy.zz.StopDelay=30
com.x.yy.zz.sourceType=t
com.x.yy.zz.sNumberInc=20000
com.x.yy.zz.sNumberMin=20000
com.x.yy.zz.sNumberMax=9980000

so -a would allow me to add a line after something
ex. -a StopDealy New
com.x.yy.zz.StopDelay=30
New





#!/bin/bash
i=1

usage()
{
        echo "test usage"
}

if [[ $# -gt 4  ]]
then
        i=2
fi

while [[ $# -gt $i ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
        -f|--file)
        file="$2"
        shift
        ;;
    -a|--after)
    sed -i  "/$2/a $3" $file
    #shift # past argument
    ;;
    -b|--before)
    sed -i "/$2/i $3" $file
        #shift
        ;;
    -d|--delete)
    sed -i "/$2/d" $file
        #shift
        ;;
        -e|--edit)
        sed -ie "s/$2/$3/g" $file
        shift
        ;;
    *)
            usage
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done
```

Comment: What does your config file look like? And what do you want it to look like after doing either -a, -b, or -d?

Comment: config file is just a huge property file with things like version number, ip address, password, etc.  -a add a desired line after match is found, -b is same but before, -d delete found line, -e find match and replace.  Most of the time I would be only working on one config file, but there is a possibility that I would want it to happen to a bunch of different config files

Comment: Edit your question and add an example.

Comment: Your script looks like a wrapper around sed native commands and syntax. What exactly is NOT working? Does all `sed ...` statements behave as you wish? Do you have problems with parameter parsing? (check quoting!)

Comment: the script works as I expect it to with a single file, but if I want to do *.config or all sp*.config I can't get it to work.  I would like to be able to run this on multiple files at once at times and at other times just a single file

Comment: How do you specify multiple files in your command line? Check quoting!

Comment: right now I do ./test.sh -f file.txt -a version "this is a test"
  this would add this is a test after the version line and if I want to do it to multiple files I would replace file with * (star)

Comment: Why didn't you checked quoting of the argument? Your script behaves exactly as you want with proper quoting of the parameters. You do not need to modify a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it yet, but this is the closest version to what I understand you want to achieve.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
        echo "Usage: $0 -f file1 -f *.txt -[abde] ... -f file3 ... -[abde] ... "
}

# Do all the required action on one file
do_work() {
    file="$1" # 1st argument must be the file to work on
    shift
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            -f|--file)   while [[ ! "$2" = -* && $# -gt 0 ]]; do shift; done ;; # Ignore any "file" since we have one to work on.
            -a|--after)  sed -i  "/$2/a $3" $file;  shift 2 ;;
            -b|--before) sed -i "/$2/i $3" $file;   shift 2 ;;
            -d|--delete) sed -i "/$2/d" $file;      shift ;;
            -e|--edit)   sed -ie "s/$2/$3/g" $file; shift 2 ;;
        esac
        shift # past argument or value
    done
}

# Check the arguments for files and print the valid ones
#   Other arguments will just be skipped
#   Invalid arguments will be displayed.
identify_files() {
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            -f|--file)   # Validate the the file exists (just in case)
                # check each following argument until next option
                # ... or end of arguments
                while [[ ! "$2" = -* && $# -gt 0 ]]; do
                    if [[ -f "$2" ]]; then
                        echo "$2"
                    else
                        echo "Error: Invalid file '$2'." >&2
                    fi
                    shift
                done ;;
            -[abe]) shift 2 ;;
            -d)     shift ;;
            -h)     usage >&2; exit ;;
            *)  echo "Invalid otpion '$1'" >&2 ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}

# Do the required actions on all files received in the options
for File in $(identify_files "$@"); do
    do_work "$File" "$@"
done

## Alternative on predefined files (not the ones received as arguments)
##    Usage: $0 -[abde] ...
#for File in $(ls *.config); do
#    do_work "$File" "$@"
#done
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I might not be doing it right, but I have tried *.txt and "*.txt" and .txt and it works on the first file, but then I get invalid file on the second valid file.  also need done before the esac and remove the esac on the bottom for loop..     Invalid otpion 'f.txt'
with f.txt being an actual file

Comment: I figured out the multiple files.  Testing now, but I think it is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Any way to do *.txt in file? or do you have to just do -f file.txt -f f.txt ?

Comment: Modified the identify_file() ... there is a loop after '-f' to check each following value until they are files. Because '*.txt' is replaced by the shell with all possible file names. But do_work might complain ... I will try to fix that to.

Comment: the little bit of testing I did seemed like it works fine that way.  to get a help menu with -h or --help would go into do_work and the identify_file section right?

Comment: Yes, it could be there (see now identify_file)... But eventually a redesign of the script would also be welcomed. While this works it could look ugly and badly organized if more and more features are added (for example, to support different operations for each file: Usage $0 -f *.txt -a somethig something_else -f *.config -d something .. each -a is for *.txt and -d is for *.config only)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I did try the help part you mentioned, but I couldn't get it to work.  I did ./script.sh -h   ./script -f -h   ./script -f file.txt -h and usage never appeared.  I added it to the other section and seems to work there.  so it needs to be in both section is seems like.  Thanks again for the help.